# Select Row values and write it in other Row

Tags: excel, search, filter, automation, calculator

Dear Community I need your help and I dont know how to solve this problem.

I need to compare the "Team(A)" "Number(D)"   (here it is **1**)
with the number "**12**(E)"
in an extra row (F)

When I have done this, the next "Team(A) "Number(D)"   (here it is **2**)
with the number "**10**(E)"
in an extra row (F) under the other and so on.

It should look like this:
Row(F)

1 - 12

2 - 10

3 - 12

4 - 16

Is there any solution ? I cant adress the column because it could be variable.
can you help me please. By the way, I am new at VBA.

Thank you so so much :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it simple and work with "Selection".
To use my example-script you would have to mark the column with the first value and then start the makro. 
(The second value would always have to be one column to the right of it and two rows below.)

```
Sub TeamCompare()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    For Each c In Selection
        If Not c.Value = "" Then
            a = c.Value
            b = ActiveSheet.Cells(c.Row + 2, c.Column + 1).Value
            ActiveSheet.Cells(c.Row, c.Column + 2).Value = a & " - " & b
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```